# Why is there no Async / Non-Blocking Support in Kafka Streams API?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am wondering why there is no non-blocking support via simple callbacks or Java's CompletableFuture or Scala Futures in the Kafka Stream API.

I do understand that ordering in a partition needs to be maintained, but across partitions I do not see the reason to achieve ordering by blocking an expensive resource: a thread.

i.e. when I let my Kafka Streams app with a call to an external service, e.g. in mapValues run on 1 server and I have more than thousands of partitions, I will probably lock up the machine because all threads are blocked. Having some API method like mapValuesAsync() would be nice here, wouldn't it?

Also just imagine on Kafka Stream App with doing several blocking operations in it's flow one would need way less partitions per each topic to run into the problem. Wasting threads doesn't look like a nice API design here.

Is there any support planned for this? Or do I oversee something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async processing is generally hard in stream processing. It's not just about ordering, but also about fault-tolerance, tracking progress etc.

It's not impossible to support though and in fact there is already a design proposal for it: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-408%3A+Add+Asynchronous+Processing+To+Kafka+Streams

Feel free to help building this feature!